# why the cursor will go back suddenly, and then go forward in TeXStudio?

Tags: texstudio

Recently I found when editing by using TeXStudio 2.12.4, the cursor will go back suddenly, and the go forward. For example, we I try to type the code

```
\ln\frac{\sqrt{2}+2}{1+\sqrt{3}}
```

then the cursor will first sit in \frac{}, but then abruptly go back to the left, and then to the right. It seem to me that TeXStudio is checking something! This makes me feel dizzy! How can I stop the cursor from going back, but just stay there or going forward? 
By the way, my configuration about auto-completion is blow:
[image]

Comment: My initial thought, which isn't necessarily correct, is that this sounds like a bug in TeXstudio, and those are better reported at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/?source=navbar